# How does one set up and configure a Butterfly Jalapeño for mining?

Tags: mining-hardware, miner-configuration, mining-setup, butterfly-labs

I just got some awesome new ASIC miners (2 Butterfly Jalapeño 5GH/s) and set them up, started running them, and only one of them was actually working. Yes I have all my cables correctly plugged in to a good power source. Can someone please tell me how to connect them so they can mine together?

Comment: I hope you didn't pay too much for them, they are pretty outdated.

Comment: got them as a gift from someone who knew nothing about Bitcoin. XD.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured this out. A simple computer restart and software re-download fixed the problem.

Comment: Can you answer your own question then? How do you set up one for mining?